# Visual Studio 2015 produces sameApp-VC.exe but try to execute sameApp.exe

Tags: visual-studio

```
My Environment:
IDE: Visual Studio 2015 Community
OS: Windows 8.1 pro
```

I am trying to use old Visual C++ project (prepared around 2010).

VisualStudio 2015 automatically updates the project file for 2015 version. And I can build the exe file.

However, I have one problem in debugging.

When I try to use "Local debugger", I have following error.

```
Program xxx\someApp.exe cannot be started.

File not found.
```

If I check the files, I found the following

- VS2015 produces a file named "someApp-VC.exe"
- VS2015 try to use "someApp.exe" in local debugger.

I am checking the options to avoid this problem, but not successfull up to now.

I would like to know the workaround for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the setting in the following menu.

[Project]->[property of someApp]->[Configuration Properties]->[Linker]->[Output File]

I changed from "Debug/someApp-VC.exe" to "Debug/someApp.exe".

Then the problem was solved.